# Is this a valid vulnerability?

Tags: security, authentication

I just found in a website what seems to be a security issue. I'm not a security expert so I would like to confirm some points before reporting the vulnerability to the website.

The website uses an "Emailed Link" for authentication. In order to receive the "Emailed Link", a user enters their email in the login form of the website. This sends the following HTTP request:

```
POST https://thewebsite.com/login
{
   "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"
}
```

If the user exists in the website's database the HTTP response code is 200, otherwise the response is 404.

This makes me think of the following vulnerabilities:

1. The website publicly gives the possibility to check if a user exists on its database, can be brute-forced.
2. Anyone can spam the users of the website by sending the previous POST request.

I'd like to hear from security experts about this, should I report this issue? Is there a common name for these types of attack?

Comment: You are right on both counts. What you are saying is self-evident, and does not need a confirmation from security experts.

Comment: Thanks for, responding :) so is there a commun name for the first vulnerability ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a vulnerability, we call this User Enumeration.